# Css image blur not works on Firefox with inline svg

Tags: css, svg

The image blur effect only works on Chrome.

Not works on Firefox,

I wonder how to fix my code to show the blur effect on Firefox ?

I refered to this post, but it seems didn't work.

[filter:blur for mozilla firefox <svg> not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595675/filterblur-for-mozilla-firefox-svg-not-working?rq=1)

### HAML

```
#slider
  #slider-container
    %img.blur{:alt => "", :src => asset_path("lms/images/light_bg.jpg")}/
```

### CSS

```
img.blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(3px);
    -o-filter: blur(3px);
    -ms-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
    filter: url(blur.svg#blur);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401219/svg-image-blur-on-firefox/20404052#20404052

Comment: Why didn't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595675/filterblur-for-mozilla-firefox-svg-not-working?rq=1 work for you? Have you added the blur.svg file that firefox requires?

Comment: HI, I need the inline svg code, not including from external file

Comment: Then you'll need to put the SVG markup in your html file and refer to it as #blur